# (android ndk) libyuv of the library convert argb to nv21 (yuv420sp) usage?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libyuv

**How to convert argb to nv21 (yuv420sp) in Android ndk?**

720 * 1280 ask if I should go to the following parameters api to change the color format of the image size.

```
argb image data size is 3,686,400. 
(width : 720 
height : 1280 
bitPerPixel : 32 
bytePerPexel: 4)
```

Api is down https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/

```
int ARGBToNV21 (const uint8 * src_argb, int src_stride_argb, 
                uint8 * dst_y, int dst_stride_y, 
                uint8 * dst_vu, int dst_stride_vu, 
                int width, int height);
```

**What is the meaning of the parameters? 
int src_stride_argb? 
int dst_stride_y? 
int int dst_stride_vu?**

Please help with a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

`dst_stride_argb` number of bytes in a row of the `dst_argb` plane.
Normally this would be the same as `dst_width`, with recommended alignment to 16 bytes for better efficiency.
If rotation of 90 or 270 is used, stride is affected. The caller should
allocate the buffer according to rotation.

`dst_stride_y` number of bytes in a row of the `dst_y` plane.
If rotation of 90 or 270 is used, stride is affected.

(Taken from [convert_argb.h](https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/source/browse/branches/m32/include/libyuv/convert_argb.h), with some modifications)